# Play framework test error

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to run some tests in Play and need to have a Play 1.x jar in the test/lib directory. With the jar, however, Play gives an error with the message:

```
Oops: UnexpectedException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException:
While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.PlayDocumentation
```

Stack trace here: https://gist.github.com/3077427

Any tips how I can include the jar and avoid this error? Jar is needed because I'm using `play.mvc.Http$Response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the Play jar to a directory outside /test/lib fixes this